# Initialize a Matrix of Pairs in Constructor

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, prolog

I'm creating a boardgame (Tzaar if curious :D) in openGL and I need to initialize my logical board with the starting pieces in each place.
In my Game classe I have the following variable:

```
std::pair<char,int> logicBoard[17][9];
```

and want to initialize it in the constructor following somewhat this example:

```
logicBoard[][] =    {
                    {(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)},
                    {(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)},
                    {(0,0),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),(0,0)},
                    {(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0)},
                    {('c',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0),('x',1),(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('c',1)},
                    {(0,0),('b',1),(0,0),('a',1),(0,0),('x',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0)},
                    {('z',1),(0,0),('a',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),('a',1),(0,0),('c',1)},
                    {(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0)},
                    {('z',1),(0,0),('x',1),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),('a',1),(0,0),('c',1)},
                    {(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0)},
                    {('z',1),(0,0),('x',1),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('x',1),(0,0),('c',1)},
                    {(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('a',1),(0,0),('x',1),(0,0),('y',1),(0,0)},
                    {('z',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0),('a',1),(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('z',1)},
                    {(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0),('y',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0)},
                    {(0,0),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('b',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),(0,0)},
                    {(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),('z',1),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)},
                    {(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),('c',1),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)}
                    };
```

But since I'm not so in depth of C++, don't know the easiest way of doing so.
Want it to be easily modified too since the board will be sent to Prolog (with the game logic) program through sockets, so it returns the modified board again to this variable.

Comment: Turn `logicBoard` into a class and build a constructor from a stream. For now you can initialise from a file and you will be able to adapt to a socket read with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a typedef, and here is a compilable snippet

```
typedef std::pair<char,int> P;
P logicBoard[17][9] = {
                    {P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0)},
                    {P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0)},
                    {P(0,0),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P(0,0)},
                    {P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0)},
                    {P('c',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0),P('x',1),P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('c',1)},
                    {P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0),P('a',1),P(0,0),P('x',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0)},
                    {P('z',1),P(0,0),P('a',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P('a',1),P(0,0),P('c',1)},
                    {P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0)},
                    {P('z',1),P(0,0),P('x',1),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P('a',1),P(0,0),P('c',1)},
                    {P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0)},
                    {P('z',1),P(0,0),P('x',1),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('x',1),P(0,0),P('c',1)},
                    {P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('a',1),P(0,0),P('x',1),P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0)},
                    {P('z',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0),P('a',1),P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('z',1)},
                    {P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0),P('y',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0)},
                    {P(0,0),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('b',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P(0,0)},
                    {P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P('z',1),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0)},
                    {P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P('c',1),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0),P(0,0)}
                    };
```

BTW depending on your Prolog interface that should be adaptable to actually exchange values. In case, maybe you want to keep P lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Container to better management of your pairs?
It would be like this:

```
std::vector< std::pair<char,int> > logicBoard;
logicBoard.push_back({0, 1});
logicBoard.push_back({'c', 1});
```

And so on...

This way if you ever need, lets say, the size of your "array" you can simply use `logicBoard.size();`